# Extension .so is missing

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, shared-libraries

I have two projects of shared libraries. Both compiles fine, but first one generates shared library format file name `shared_lib_1.so`, while second one is without `so` extension - `shared_lib_1`. I compared all settings in these libraries in my eclipse - both are `-shared` and other settings are same.

Why second lib is without `.so` extension?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to put the `.so` in the name somewhere?

Comment: my both projects are without `lib` and `.so` suffixes and prefixes. I expect Eclipse to somehow manage it.